# How to fix No value specified for parameter 2 error

Tags: java, sql, mysql

I'm currently new to JAVAfx and I am trying to create a signup user method. When I run the program I get this error:

```
java.sql.SQLException: No value specified for parameter 2
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:130)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:122)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.execute(ClientPreparedStatement.java:379)
    at com.example.demo2/com.example.demo2.DatabaseHandler.signUpUser(DatabaseHandler.java:34)
    at com.example.demo2/com.example.demo2.registerController.lambda$initialize$0(registerController.java:37)
```

```
    public void signUpUser(String firstName, String lastName, String email, String password) {

        String insert = "INSERT INTO " + Const.USERS_TABLE + "(" + Const.USERS_FIRSTNAME + "," + "VALUES(????)";

        try {
            PreparedStatement preparedStatement = getDbConnection().prepareStatement(insert);

            preparedStatement.setString(1,firstName);
            preparedStatement.setString(1,lastName);
            preparedStatement.setString(1,email);
            preparedStatement.setString(1,password);

            preparedStatement.execute();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```

Any help would be great. I think this method is faulty.

Thanks

Comment: The error is telling you exactly what is wrong as you appear to be assigning all SQL variables to the same parameter, parameter 1.

Comment: Thanks I have just noticed. I changed the parameters and it has produced another error:  You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'VALUES('q''a''a''ss')' at line 1

Comment: Shouldn't there be commas?

Comment: Have you gone through the relevant tutorials on this topic? You can find some resources both [here](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/sql/info) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/mysql/info)

Comment: yes I am getting really confused. I am very new to this, so I could be making stupid mistakes.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels managed to solve the issue it was the commas lol. These small mistakes stress you out!! thanks for the advice and your time (: